# Linking page title block to home - best practices?

Tags: xhtml

I do most if not all my sites to have the page title block (generally a styled h1 on my pages) to link back to the home page.

Should this be linked on the first page, i.e. the home page? I read that this shouldn't be linked, but one thing I do when I go to a page for the first time is mouseover the title to check the status bar to see if it will send me home.

What I'm asking is best practises for this... should the home page's title link back to itself for future reference for the user?

Comment: do you mean the title of the entire site? (ie stackoverlfow) or the specific title of the current page (ie Linking page title block to home - best practises?) because the latter seems wrong to me.

Comment: i mean the title of the entire site - i use the h1 tag

Comment: in that case: link it. i ALWAYS use to the title or logo for a site to take me 'home'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I understand the logic behind a page not linking to itself, I personally think the title block is a defensible exception.  So I think you should link it to the home page, even on the home page.

Comment: User testing shows this is a problem that need not exist. Users mistakenly click on the title since it is clickable, and the page reloads, and users spend a couple of extra seconds wondering where they are. It's a waste of time for the user when it takes two seconds to NOT do it for the developer.

Comment: Do run-of-the-mill users never look in their status bar? Won't they click it and see the throbber spinning? After looking at the layout of useit.com, should I care what he has to say?

Comment: @Robert: You mean just like *your* website http://www.norimek.com/blog/??  Bit of pot and kettle, isn't it?

Comment: @alex: Yes you should care. He's about usability, not pretty. And no, users don't look at the status bar. @monkey: The audience for my site  is pretty much me. But good catch, I'll have to go see if I can edit BlogEngine.net to change it; it's not my software. :-)

Comment: I'm going to stick to linking my titles to home... Even if it is on the home page. I doubt any user would click the page title and expect it to go anywhere else but home. And I provide a title attribute '*site title* Home'

Comment: @Alex: I have read through most of useit.com, over the past few years, and respect the content greatly... but the site itself is kinda lame.  That said, good content always trumps "pretty", IMHO.

Comment: @monkey - agreed with content making a site, not design.

Answer (score 2):

See sites such as facebook - the facebook logo always links to the homepage.

It's a strong convention, and I try to utilize it where ever practicable.

Answer (score 0):

There should never be links on the page that link to itself. According to research by [Jakob Nielsen](http://www.useit.com/), this is a bad idea. Further reading [here](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20031222.html) (#10) and [here](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20031110.html) (also #10 in that list).

Comment: I don't really agree with his points on this. For example, on SO I often press the QUESTIONS button to refresh the page, even though it's the page I'm at. I do the same in many sites. Never prevent me an easy way to access the same content repeatedly

Comment: F5 (or right click->refresh) does the same thing as clicking the questions tab if you're already there. There is evidence that self-linking items are bad for the user, why ignore it? Do you know better than a guy who has spent his life in human factors? An anecdotal use-case is not evidence.

Comment: Also, this site doesn't exactly cater to the "average user." The average user is easily confused, unfortunately.